# i want to resize the image and save in folder using yii

Tags: yii

i have installed **simpleimage**
extension in

> protected/extensions/simple_image.php and
>   protected/extensions/CSimpleImage.php
>   this is my config/main.php

```
'simple_image'=>array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.CSimpleImage',
            ),
```

in my view file.

```
$file="images/image.jpg";
$img = Yii::app()->simple_image->load($file);
$img->resizeToWidth(128);
$img->save("newLogo.jpg");
```

and i got error like this:-

> Error 500 getimagesize(images/image.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting this error in the extension you are using. In your simple_image file you have a function named `function__construct`

```
  function __construct($filename) {
      $this->image_info = $image_info = getimagesize($filename);//here you are getting this erro
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
```

so that means your path to the image is incorrect. you can write it as

```
$file=yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/image.jpg'
```